# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' for display command

Tags: linux, bash, syntax

I want to open a gif file using linux command.The file's name is "Simulation of electrical activity in the heart during fibrillation (with comparison with experiment).gif".

I use the following command:

```
$display <Simulation of electrical activity in the heart during fibrillation\(\with comparison with experiment\)\.gif>
```

It gives me

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

What's wrong with it? Thank you!

Comment: Here is the command : $display <Simulation of electrical activity in the heart during fibrillation\(\with comparison with experiment\)\.gif>.

Comment: Remove the `<` and `>` if those were in the command, and the ``\ `` should be before the `(` and `)`, not after. For convenience, use tab completion which automatically escapes the filename: `display Simu`<tab>.

Comment: It says unable to open X server `' @ display.c/DisplayImageCommand/420.

Comment: "unable to open X server" means, well, just that. You don't have a correct `DISPLAY` environment variable telling it how to contact your graphical display, or the Xauthority or other supporting content is wrong. There are several possible reasons your X server could be inaccessible, and the question doesn't provide enough detail to focus on any one of them as more likely than any other.

Comment: ...moreover, just because you have a different problem after fixing the question you asked about doesn't mean that that first question was not, in fact, correctly solved.

Answer (score 6):

The reason

```
display <filename>
```

gives you a `syntax error near unexpected token newline` is that the arrow brackets in whatever documentation you were following were not intended to be taken literally.

A `<` indicates that the thing that follows is a filename to be used as input on stdin, and a `>` indicates that the thing that follows is a filename to be used for output on stdout; thus, a `>` at the very end of your command is a syntax error, because it expects a file name to follow, not a newline.

Rather, use:

```
display filename
```

...in this particular case:

```
display 'Simulation of electrical activity in the heart during fibrillation (with comparison with experiment).gif'
```